# How to have dynamic rowspan with antd react

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to prepare a table with dynamic rowspan in antd(data will be dynmaic)

I have data like below.

Wanted to display as below. Can you please help ?

`[{"col1":"temp1","col2":"1","col3":"x"},
{"col1":"temp1","col2":"1","col3":"y"},
{"col1":"temp1","col2":"2","col3":"z"},
{"col1":"temp2","col2":"3","col3":"a"}];`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

we can write custom render method to resolve this issue.
sample :

```
render: (value, row, index) => {
        const obj = {
          children: value,
          props: {},
        };
        if (index >= this.state.branch_new_index) {
          for (let i = 0; index + i !== metrics.length
                && value === metrics[index + i].branch  && 
                metrics[index].product === metrics[index + i].product; i += 1) {
            obj.props.rowSpan = i + 1;
            this.state.branch_count = i + 1;
          }
          this.state.branch_new_index = index + this.state.branch_count;
          if (index + 1 >= metrics.length) {
            this.state.branch_new_index = 0;
          }
        } else {
          obj.props.rowSpan = 0;
          if (index + 1 >= metrics.length) {
            this.state.branch_new_index = 0;
          }
        }
        return obj;
      },
```